# YII Migration History Not Being Saved Into Database

Tags: php, yii

I'm using YII 1.1.12. When I do:

```
yiic migrate
```

inside the protected folder of my application, I get told that there is a new migration to be applied. I answer "Yes" so that the migration would be applied. After a while, I get:

```
*** applied m121220_121256_initialize_database (time: 6.060s)
Migrated up successfully.
```

All is fine up to this point. Then when I type 'yiic migrate', instead of being told that there is no new migration, I get told that:

```
Yii Migration Tool v1.0 (based on Yii v1.1.12)

Total 1 new migration to be applied:
    m121220_121256_initialize_database
```

Apply the above migration? (yes|no) [no]:

WhenI check the tbl_migration table, the only thing in there is the base migration. There's nothing aboutinitialize_database.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised the problem was that the sql commands I was running straight from PHPMyAdmin contained a transaction. When I removed the lines about transactions, the database row in the yii_migration table was inserted successfully. I'm not sure why this should be, but there it is.

Answer (score 1):

Does your migration create the database? If so it might be throwing Yii off, and it's creating the migration structure at the start and then can't insert into, I'm not sure what the behaviour would be.

If `m121220_121256_initialize_database` is doing any kind of destructive work then it's probably a good idea to use `yiic migrate mark 121220_121256` to manually set the database to this migration after you've ran it.

That way you can do further tests to see whether it's a migration bug or something destructive in the migration like dropping/creating a database.